# Use a CSS Bootstrap class (card) only on bigger screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've used a Bootstrap 4 template for my web application that included a form inside a card definition. I've realized that for it to be more mobile friendly ( = use better the space) the card container might be taken away. I was going to eliminate the card class in every form, but then I realized it would be great to keep such setup for the bigger screens.

I think I might use media queries and such, but these not being my classes but Bootstrap's I'm not sure how I could hide them in "some cases". Is it possible to do this via css? Thanks!

Current template:

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
              <div class="card mt-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">
                    </div>
                     <!--- FORM DEFINITION -->
                </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I dont really understand the actual question. Are you just asking how to hide the card and form on some screen widths?

Comment: @Zim the idea would be to show the card structure when it's a bigger screen, and let it "dissapear" (no borders) when it's a small (phone) device, modifying the html that I have as little as possible (quite a few of them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the card gives you paddding and a border. The padding Spacing utils are responsive, so it's easy to adjust the Card padding as needed. For example, 3 padding units on `lg` and up, 0 padding units less than `lg`...

```
p-lg-3 p-0
```

Then use a simple media query for the borders...

```
@media (max-width:992px) {
    .card {
        border-width:0;
    }
}
```

Note `-xs` is no longer used in Bootstrap 4.

https://www.codeply.com/go/BIxuYmb266

Comment: Excellent, works perfect, this is a much more efficient and shorter version of what I was doing. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add specific class to your `<div class=“card-body”>` and add new styles in media query.

Comment: I think that's the way to go, in the end. For now I'm approaching it as new classes that replicate the card/card-body Bootstrap ones. I didn't want to rewrite them but I can't see an alternative. In those new classes, I'll be using the media queries so they only come up in the bigger screens.